# Hooking ExtTextOutW not gives the text with proper information

Tags: winapi, hook

I am creating an application that can get text from the selected rectangle on any window. So I am doing this by hooking the ExtTextOut(A/W), TextOut(A/W), DrawText(A/W) apis.
I am able to retrieve the text from windows but in some special cases I am not able to get the text properly.
When I tried to debug it I saw that the HDC parameter of ExtTextOutW can not been used to get the HWND, because when I try to call WindowFromDC(hdc), it returns NULL HWND.

I tried to find out the reason then I found that this HDC is memoryDC so is there any way to get the HWND from that memory DC.

So Please somebody help me to get the actual HWND from the HDC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to *follow* that `HDC` as it is likely that it will be `BitBlt()`, or similar, to a `HDC` that is associated with an actual `HWND`:

- cache the text written to memory `HDC`s
- hook `BitBlt()`, and others, and check if the the source `HDC` of the `BitBlt()` is one of the memory `HDC`s that has had text written to it. If it is, check if the destination `HDC` has a `HWND` and if not then it is a memory `HDC` which must again be followed

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply.
Actually I have tried BitBlt but it also doesn't fulfil my requirement. I don't know why but the hooked BitBlt is been called only for once(for the main window). 
I think either I am doing something wrong or there is some other problem. I was thinking that for every sub window BitBlt should be called but it is not.

Please suggest.

Comment: There are variants of `BitBlt()`, like `StretchBlt()`. How do you patch the import address tables? What if a new DLL is loaded? Do you detect that and patch it? (by _patch_ I mean _hook_). `BitBlt()` by itself is not enough, as the text will have already been written. But combined with the text outputting functions it may provide your answer. As a test, suggest just printing the arguments to a log file (or somewhere) of the text outputting functions and `BitBlt()` and friends and see if the `HDC`s match.

Comment: Thanks you friend for your suggestion.
I have tried some variants of BitBlt, like : StretchBlt, StretchDIBits, and insert the code related to Logs but nothing will be printed in my log file. It means not any hooked function(StretchBlt or StretchDIBits) is called.
Actually I am new in hooking so may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have tried a lot but My hooked BitBlt method called just once. Please help me. I don't know how to step further.

Comment: @vab711, I done this once with a specific application I needed to monitor. What I described in my answer is how that particular application behaved. Remember that there are two ways to call a function: one is when the function name is used in the program code, which results in an entry in the import address table and is intercepted by patching IAT and the other is using `GetProcAddress()`. If the application is using `GetProcAddress()` you need to intercept it and return your hooking function address instead of `TextOut`, `BitBlt()`, etc. Hooking functions is non-trivial.

Comment: You are right, I have to hook BitBlt method to get the hdc. Now there is another issue that is I have to Invalidate the hooked window to invoke all the text related APIs, but I am not able to invalidate the another window.